# Add bullet to multiple textarea and hidden textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I'm trying to add bullets to multiple textarea. This works fine when the textareas are not hidden, however I'd like to be able to add bullets to newly created textareas (click on the button "Add New". Ideally I'd like also newly created bullets to go to the next line rather than to be displayed side by side.

```js
$(document).ready() 
$('.add-bullet').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('textarea').val(function(idx, value){
        return value + '\u2022';
    });
    return false;
});

(function($) {
  "use strict";
  
  var itemTemplate = $('.workExperience-template').detach(),
      editArea = $('.workExperience-area'),
      itemNumber = 1;
  
  $(document).on('click', '.workExperience-area .add', function(event) {
    var item = itemTemplate.clone();
    item.find('[name]').attr('name', function() {
      return $(this).attr('name') + '_' + itemNumber;
    });
    ++itemNumber;
    item.prependTo(editArea);
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.workExperience-area .rem', function(event) {
    editArea.children('.workExperience-template').last().remove();
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.workExperience-area .del', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target),
        row = target.closest('.workExperience-template');
    row.remove();
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textarea">
 <div><a href="#" class = "add-bullet">Add bullet</a></div>
    <textarea id="todolist" class="todolist" name="todolist" placeholder="Write something.." ></textarea>
    </div>
 
    <div class="hidden">
    <div class="workExperience-template">
    <div class="textarea">
    <div><a href="#" class = "add-bullet">Add bullet</a></div>
    <textarea id="list" class="list" name="tata" placeholder="Write something.." ></textarea>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="workExperience-area">
    <button type="button" class="add buttonBlueAddField">Add New</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach click event on newly created `anchor`s:

```js
$(document).ready() 
$('.add-bullet').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('textarea').val(function(idx, value){
        return value + '\u2022';
    });
    return false;
});

(function($) {
  "use strict";
  
  var itemTemplate = $('.workExperience-template').detach(),
      editArea = $('.workExperience-area'),
      itemNumber = 1;
  
  $(document).on('click', '.workExperience-area .add', function(event) {
    var item = itemTemplate.clone();
    item.find('[name]').attr('name', function() {
      return $(this).attr('name') + '_' + itemNumber;
    });
    ++itemNumber;
    
    item.find(".add-bullet").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('textarea').val(function(idx, value){
        return value + '\u2022\n';
    });
    return false;
});
  $(".textarea").next().append(item);
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.workExperience-area .rem', function(event) {
    editArea.children('.workExperience-template').last().remove();
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.workExperience-area .del', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target),
        row = target.closest('.workExperience-template');
    row.remove();
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textarea">
 <div><a href="#" class = "add-bullet">Add bullet</a></div>
    <textarea id="todolist" class="todolist" name="todolist" placeholder="Write something.." ></textarea>
    </div>
 
    <div class="hidden">
    <div class="workExperience-template">
    <div class="textarea">
    <div><a href="#" class = "add-bullet">Add bullet</a></div>
    <textarea id="list" class="list" name="tata" placeholder="Write something.." ></textarea>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="workExperience-area">
    <button type="button" class="add buttonBlueAddField">Add New</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, but now the new created textarea appear above the textarea with the bullet, while it should appear below i.e. any new created textarea should appear just above the Add New button.